This page can't load Google Maps correctly - even with billing and API key in place
We have an issue where we get the error "This page can't load Google Maps correctly".
Steps are as follows:
The instance was created on Google Cloud (without billing in test phase) and API generated and entered.
It worked but failed after some time with a JavaScript Error: **ClientBillingNotEnabledMapError Error:  You have not enabled billing on your project. You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project associated to this client ID, here.
We updated the instance with billing information entered but the JS error persisted.
Then created a new API and entered that. The JS error is no longer there but when typing in the lookup field the error message above occurs.
This happens with the API key restricted to the website in question and without restriction.
Note that this is used in conjunction with the Chauffeur taxi hailing plugin for WordPress, API is entered in the plugin. The API is therefore not appended to the embed string but entered in a field in the plugin.
Another question on here with the same issue mentioned that there was a hard-coded API somewhere else that clashed, but that seems unlikely here.
Tried turning various settings on and off, including removing restricting the API key to the web address.
Removed and re-entered all information in the plugin
Removed geolocation and reactivated that

OK, figured it out.
Even though it was all working before, somehow at the entering of billing information the Maps APIs were disabled. So one could create API keys but they wouldn't work unless the APIs are enabled. Finding that place and enabling them solved the issue.
Google Cloud > Other Google products > Google Maps Platform
Screen Shot
